# Attribute ddata-horizontalposition not allowed on element li at this point- w3c validator

Tags: html-lists, w3c-validation

w3c validator shows this error:

```
Attribute ddata-horizontalposition not allowed on element li at this point.

<li data-text-id="#bannerscollection_kenburns_photoText4" ddata-horizontalPosition="center" data-verticalPosition="center" data-initialZoom="1" data-finalZoom="1"></li>
```

Someone please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this:

```
<li data-text-id="#bannerscollection_kenburns_photoText4" data-horizontalPosition="center" data-verticalPosition="center" data-initialZoom="1" data-finalZoom="1"></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

The attribute `ddata-horizontalPosition` is not allowed in HTML5.

It probably should be

```
data-horizontalPosition="center"
```

See [http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes).